# MySql: Add information into multiple tables with one command

Tags: mysql

I am using php and mysql. I want to do an insert into multiple tables with one command. Can this be done with a stored procedure or a function? If so, could I then call this function with php?

eg (psuedo code, I don't code in mysql often):

```
hash %list = {"ip", "network_table"; "gateway", "network_table"; "name", "server_table");

function lookup (string $s)
{
    //look up the value of s in a hash and return the corresponding table

    $table = $list[s]

    return $table;
}

function doTheInserting (hash $input) //or hash_ref? or array?
{
    for each $key in $input{
        $table = &lookup $key
        insert into $table ($key) values ($value)
    }
}
```

Some problems would arise if I have multiple "NOT NULL" columns. Is this a viable way? Is there a better way if I need to go about entering information into multiple tables at once?

Comment: I don't understand the "problems would arise if I have multiple NOT NULL columns."  Like what?

Comment: The way I have it written, I would be trying to insert one $value and one $key at a time... I guess I could just push $value and $key onto two arrays and then do them all at once. I guess I don't know mysql welll enough to know if what I want to do is possible.

Comment: One by key do you mean column?  So you would essentially be doing `INSERT INTO t1 (col1) VALUES ('col1'); INSERT INTO t1 (col2) VALUES ('col2') -- ...etc.)`?

Comment: what is the reason you must use "one command"?  Could you create a transaction using many commands and then have rollback your transaction on failure?  what storage engine are you using?

Comment: I would like one command for ease of coding the application that will be inserting/updating the table. If that application could just send a list of values and columns, I'd rather MYSQL know which tables to put them in.

Comment: I think the answer may include temporary tables... It is the only thing I can find.